# Matrix Proof of Schur Orthogonality

Tags: representation-theory

It seems to me like the [coordinate statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations#Coordinates_statement) of Schur's Orthogonality relations

$$ \sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \Gamma^{(\lambda)}(R)_{nm}^* \Gamma^{(\mu)}(R)_{n'm'} = \delta_{\lambda \mu} \delta_{n n'} \delta_{mm'} \frac{|G|}{l_{\lambda}} $$

comes from the fact that, given size $l_{\lambda}$ unitary matrices $\Gamma$ satisfying

$$\Gamma^* \Gamma = I$$

which form a representation of a group $G = \{R\}$ of order $|G|$, so that

$$\Gamma(R)^* \Gamma(R) = I$$

we simply sum this relation for all $R \in G$ giving

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \Gamma(R)^* \Gamma(R) = |G|I$$

so that it's coordinate expression

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \Gamma(R)^*_{nm} \Gamma(R)_{nm'} = |G|\delta_{mm'}$$

i.e.

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn} \Gamma(R)_{nm'} = |G| \delta_{mm'}$$

**apparently**, on multiplying across both sides by $\delta_{nn'}$,

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn}  \delta_{nn'} \Gamma(R)_{nm'} = |G| \delta_{nn'} \delta_{mm'}$$

gives us

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} l_{\lambda} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn} \Gamma(R)_{n'm'} = |G| \delta_{nn'} \delta_{mm'}$$

**almost**, reducing to Schur.

**Question:** Is this step correct? *I don't see why it's justified*. **If not, can we modify this method to prove the theorem?**

**Edit:** Think I got it. Given
$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn} \Gamma(R)_{nm'} = |G| \delta_{mm'}$$

We note $\sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \delta_{nn} =  l_{\lambda}$ so that

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn} \Gamma(R)_{nm'} = \frac{|G|}{l_{\lambda}}\sum_{n=1}^{l_{\lambda}} \delta_{nn} \delta_{mm'}$$

gives

$$\sum_{R \in G}^{|G|} \Gamma(R)^{*t}_{mn} \Gamma(R)_{n'm'} = \frac{|G|}{l_{\lambda}} \delta_{nn'} \delta_{mm'}$$

Also, any thoughts on using this approach to get the final $\delta$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're barking up the wrong tree. You can't prove a result about representation theory of groups using only statements about matrices without connection to the group properties.

Also your manipulations are not valid. In the first attempt, you multiplied through by a quantity with an index that was bound on the left-hand side and free on the right-hand side. In the second attempt, you dropped a summation from an equation, assuming without justification that the equality of the sums implies the equality of the summands.

There are lots of proofs of the orthogonality relations out there; I don't think this is the place to write down another one. [This one](http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/d.vvedensky/groups/Chapter4.pdf) seems relatively accessible to me. My suggestion would be to read one of the existing proofs and try to understand where it makes essential use of the group properties and why it's not possible to derive the same result without making such use. If you have questions about existing proofs, you can always ask another question about them here.

Comment: Wow, I think that was the quickest downvote I ever saw. Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I am not barking up the wrong tree, not a fair thing to say, this should be a comment at best, especially on a bounty question, would be great if you would remove this, especially with such a dismissive comment. As regards what I've posted in my edit, it seems to me we just need to justify that it holds for each term in the sum separately , which amounts to assuming it is true & working backwards in your links proof, ending up at Schur's lemma, *hardly* barking up the wrong tree... The point of a bounty answer is a deep illustrative answer not just links and side comments :(